# Initial sqlalchemy query is slow to return result

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am new to sqlalchemy and am running into performance issues on a simple query against an existing table. The select query is filtering on the primary key of the table and returning only that value. It's taking nearly two seconds for the result to actually be returned even though the query runs fast (see bottom of log). It also only happens on the first query that gets run. Looking at the log, sqlalchemy appears to be running several additional queries, which is at least partly responsible for the slow down (they aren't run on subsequent queries). I am trying to understand why it's running these extra queries and if it's possible to prevent it from doing so.

```
INFO:     SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
2020-02-27 15:08:42,292 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO:     ()
2020-02-27 15:08:42,366 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'
INFO:     SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'
2020-02-27 15:08:42,367 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO:     ()
2020-02-27 15:08:42,522 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
INFO:     SELECT DATABASE()
2020-02-27 15:08:42,522 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO:     ()
2020-02-27 15:08:42,666 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine show collation where `Charset` = 'utf8mb4' and `Collation` = 'utf8mb4_bin'
INFO:     show collation where `Charset` = 'utf8mb4' and `Collation` = 'utf8mb4_bin'
2020-02-27 15:08:42,667 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO:     ()
2020-02-27 15:08:42,743 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
INFO:     SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2020-02-27 15:08:42,743 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO:     ()
2020-02-27 15:08:42,832 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
INFO:     SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2020-02-27 15:08:42,833 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO:     ()
2020-02-27 15:08:42,909 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test collated returns' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8mb4) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin AS anon_1
INFO:     SELECT CAST('test collated returns' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8mb4) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin AS anon_1
2020-02-27 15:08:42,910 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO:     ()
2020-02-27 15:08:43,130 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:     BEGIN (implicit)
Start Query: %s SELECT orders.order_number AS orders_order_number 
FROM orders 
WHERE orders.order_number = %s 
 LIMIT %s
2020-02-27 15:08:43,132 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT orders.order_number AS orders_order_number 
FROM orders 
WHERE orders.order_number = %s 
 LIMIT %s
INFO:     SELECT orders.order_number AS orders_order_number 
FROM orders 
WHERE orders.order_number = %s 
 LIMIT %s
2020-02-27 15:08:43,132 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (13145, 1)
INFO:     (13145, 1)

Query Complete!
Query Time: %f 0.0731968879699707 (Generated using: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/performance.html)

Total Time: 1.8191041946411133 (Generated by wrapping query call)
```

Comment: Is it possible that establishing the connection is the slow part? If you have reverse DNS lookups enabled the connection can take some time.

Comment: Looks like you're right! When I pushed my test script to our server and ran it, the performance problems went away. Thanks for the help!